# How to add a claim to an existing Wikidata item, from command line?

Tags: tool-request, wikidata

I want to add to Wikidata this claim:

[Embassy of Switerland, London](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q5369879) - [is operated by](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P137) - [Switzerland](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q39)

... using my Linux command-line.
Launching a web request via curl is OK too.

How to do?

I have seen [Wikidata-CLI](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-cli) and [Wikidata-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wikidata-sdk), unfortunately they only seem to support read-only operations. None of the [external tools listed at Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Tools/External_tools) seem to apply either.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [wikidata-agent](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-agent) for that:

```
curl -XPOST http://your.wikidata.agent.instance/claim -d 'entity=Q5369879&property=P137&value=Q39'
```

**[Update]**: you can now actually [add claims using wikidata-cli](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-cli/blob/master/docs/write_operations.md#wd-add-claim)